# Date format changes to 'mm/dd/yyyy' when posting data to web api method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, post, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Web API.

I want to be able to download a csv file on click on a button.

Below is my jquery call to the api 'exportfruit'

```
function downloadFile(){
var data = {
    StartDate: this.model.get('StartDate'),
    Name: this.model.get('Name')
};

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'api/fruitapi/exportFruit';
form.method = 'POST';
form.style.display = 'none';
for (i in data) {
    if (data[i] != "") {
        var inputElement = document.createElement('textarea');
        inputElement.name = i;
        inputElement.value = data[i];
        form.appendChild(inputElement);
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
```

and my web api action is as below

```
[ActionName("ExportFruit")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostExportFruit(SomeModel model)
{
    // for now i am just testing the value returned from model.
    string csv = "some data from db";
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StringContent(csv);
    //a text file is actually an octet-stream (pdf, etc)
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    //we used attachment to force download
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "testfile.csv";
    return result;    
}
```

now the problem I am facing is that I am passing date as 'dd/mm/yyyy' but in the web api action it converts date into 'mm/dd/yyyy'

So for example,

if I have a date like

- 1/2/2012 this is converted to 2/1/2012
- if 22/10/2012 (todays date) is converted to 01/01/0001

How do I fix this ?

I had similar problem when passing json data which I fixed by using [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/5136406.aspx) But I have no idea on how to go about on this one.

Please help me on this, as there is hardly any content available on internet for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change StartDate's type, Datetime to String.

Then, post to action, ParseExact string to datetime

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.StartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.EndDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: I know this approach, its my backup plan ;) But there has to be a way to do this using DateTime object too right ? Thanks anyways @ChunHao Tang

Comment: with no other solution, I ended up using this method. Thanks @ChunHao Tang